# inView is not defined lazy-instant-render.js

Tags: javascript, lazy-loading

My website has a large number of photographs on the first page which is slowing down the performance of the page and making the load time far too long. To combat this I found lazy-instant-render.js which will prevent all images from loading when the page is ready. I get this error in console: inView is not defined.

```
// Performance tests such as Google Lighthouse often complain about below the fold images while lazy loading 
// techniques may introduce a flash effect for images on bigger screens
// This snippet shows a solution to instantly display images as if loaded using src="" while maintaining 
// the lazy loading benefit on smaller screens.

// Tip: a second and potentially better technique is to rewrite lazy loaded images to regular src="" images in a Service Worker.

// this snippet depends on in-view (5kb)
// @link https://github.com/camwiegert/in-view/

// tiny cross browser domready method
// @link https://gist.github.com/dciccale/4087856
var DOMReady = function(a,b,c){b=document,c='addEventListener';b[c]?b[c]('DOMContentLoaded',a):window.attachEvent('onload',a)}

// requestAnimationframe
var RAF = window.requestAnimationframe || setTimeout;

var lazyToken = 'data-lzy';

// display image
var lazyResolve = function(el) {

    // already loaded
    if (!el.hasAttribute(lazyToken)) {
        return;
    }

    // verify if image is hidden by parent
    if (el.offsetParent !== null) {

        // remove lazy marker (to mark as completed)
        el.removeAttribute(lazyToken);

        // requestAnimationFrame to prevent layout trashing
        RAF(function() {
            el.setAttribute('src', el.getAttribute(lazyToken));
        });
    }
}

// setup lazy load method
DOMReady(function() {
    inView('['+lazyToken+']').on('enter', lazyResolve);
});

// instantly load visible images on render
var mutationObserver = window.MutationObserver || window.WebKitMutationObserver,
    observer;
if (mutationObserver) {
    observer = new mutationObserver(function(mutations) {
        mutations.forEach(function(mutation) {
            var node;
            for (var i = 0; i < mutation.addedNodes.length; i++) {
                node = mutation.addedNodes[i];
                if (node.nodeName === 'IMG' && node.hasAttribute(lazyToken)) {
                    if (inView.is(node)) {

                        // start download
                        new Image().src = node.getAttribute(lazyToken);

                        // display image with requestAnimationFrame
                        lazyResolve(node);
                    }
                }
            }
        });
    });
    observer.observe(document.documentElement, {
        childList: true,
        subtree: true
    });
}
```

Comment: It seems that the `lazy-instant-render` utility you found depends on another utility called `in-view` (see the comment in the code of your question `// this snippet depends on in-view (5kb) // @link https://github.com/camwiegert/in-view/`). Are you importing this utility?

Comment: @mgarcia I am not importing this utility, how do I use it?

Comment: How are you importing `lazy-instant-render`?

Comment: @mgarcia I have just added the code to my main js file.

Comment: I don't see the new code in your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use the new the standard loading="lazy"-attribute functionality to lazy load images (and iframes if needed). Additionally to support older browsers as well, you could use the polyfill that I‘ve developed for this aspect: https://github.com/mfranzke/loading-attribute-polyfill

Comment: yea this is extremely useful!, how come nobody told me this before!